# How to create multimedia input field that would take text, picture, gif like Facebook/Twitter "Create Post" input field

Tags: javascript, html

Please can someone help me with how to create an input field that would take text, pictures, gif, attachment etc. just like Facebook/twitter/Quora's "Create Post" input field... it would be good to see a plugin that can help with that or if I can create it myself! thanks in advance... I know what you are about to say, I did my research and I couldn't find anything that help me with building. I just want something like a 101 of such palette so that I can continue build it... I will also like to add my own conventions (like Ctrl + B to bold etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this.

**"post"**  Sends the form-data as an **HTTP post transaction**. The HTML **action** attribute is used to specify where the form data is to be sent to the server after submission of the form. It can be used in the  element.
**URL:** It is used to specify the URL of the document where the data to be sent after the submission of the form.

All you need now is to specify a **textarea** where that post will be sent and style the button to say "Post" instead of the regular "Submit".

```
<form action="/action_page.php" method="post">
  <label for="fname">First name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><be>
  <label for="lname">Last name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"><br><be>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: nope! the objective is to create an input field that works just like our Facebook/twitter/Watsapp input field (not a form!) taking different kinds of data gif, images, text alongside rendering appropriately. thanks for trying.